# Map of lists of move-only type won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to use a `std::map< Key, std::list< std::unique_ptr< T > > >` .

Am I missing some fundamental reason why this is not possible ?

I've reduced the code giving the error to the following:

```
// A simple move-only type
struct moveonly
{
  moveonly(moveonly const&) = delete;
  moveonly& operator= (moveonly const&) = delete;

  moveonly() = default;
  moveonly(moveonly&&) = default;
  moveonly& operator= (moveonly&&) = default;

  ~moveonly() noexcept {}
};

typedef std::list< moveonly > list_t;
typedef std::pair< int, list_t > pair_t;

// Even just trying to default construct such a pair fails
pair_t pr;
```

I'm using MSVC November CTP. The error is **"attempting to reference a deleted function"** for the copy constructor of moveonly. This is being instantiated in the copy constructor of `std::list`. I have no idea why `std::list`'s copy constructor would be getting instantiated, when all I've done is attempt to default construct the pair.

Comment: It compiles ok with GCC, and I don't think it's relying on a non-standard extension ... looks like a bug in the MSVC library.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I've confirmed it's an issue with the VC Nov 13 CTP, compiles fine in VC 2013.