# How can I find the source of a copy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, compiler-errors, unique-ptr

I have some container-using code that is causing me grief. The issue is that I want to put a smart pointer (unique_ptr) in one of the subfields. Eg:

```
struct subrecord {
    int id;
    int handle;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<some_really_big_record>> update; // <-- Problem field
};

struct database {
    std::map <std::string, subrecord> name_subrec_map;
    std::vector <std::string> a_names;
    std::vector <std::string> b_names;
};
```

Everything compiled just fine until I tried adding that `update` field. Once I did that, the compiler started to complain that there's no usable copy operator for that unique_ptr. That's fair enough, it isn't supposed to have one. I wasn't intending these map entries to be copied anyway.

However, the compiler is not telling me where in my code this copy is coming from. There's rather a lot of it by now. Is there any good way to tell? I've tried searching for references to `update` and `name_subrec_map` and commenting them out, but haven't had any luck at all. The only thing that gets rid of the error is commenting out that `update` field itself.

I'd hate to have to switch to a shared_ptr, just because I can't find the dang copy.

Comment: Your compiler gave you an error message but no line/file to go with it?

Comment: Try compiling with vaguely recent versions of g++ or clang. They will tell you exactly where the copy is being instantiated. Actually, any version that supports `unique_ptr` should tell you that.

Comment: @juanchopanza If it supports unique_ptr isn't it by default a vaguely recent version of g++/clang?

Comment: @Borgleader - The line numbers it is giving me for this error are all off in the compiler's own template code. VS2012 error messages FTL!

Comment: @T.E.D.: the line numbers are not all in the compiler's code. look for the file names.

Comment: [Related issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160396/map-of-lists-of-move-only-type-wont-compile)

Comment: unique_ptr is not copyable (although it is movable). As a result subrecord is also non-copyable (but is movable). if you are copying subrecord anywhere it is going to give you the same error. As a test put subrecord( const subrecord & ) = delete; subrecord( subrecord&& ) = default; Might make it easier to find the error in your code then

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Oh yes they are. Every single error message is either calling out a line in `...\VC\include\list` or in `...\VC\include\xmemory0`, except for the last that just points to the first template instantiation off in a header file of mine.

Comment: @Borgleader, GCC 4.4 supported `unique_ptr` but is not very recent (although it would still tell you where the copy was required from)

Comment: he can't run it through a debugger to find compiler errors..

Comment: @T.E.D. are you _sure_ the compiler isn't also showing you the call stack that led to the error inside the library? GCC and Clang will print something like "required from ...; required from ...;" to show how an error in a header was reached, so you can trace it back to your own code. I would be amazed if VC++ doesn't do that too. The relevant lines might not start with the word "error"

Comment: @JonathanWakely - Be amazed, because it doesn't. At least not the VS2012 build I'm using. Perhaps more recent versions of the compiler are better.

Comment: @Borgleader - After futzing around with things as suggested, I think you are most likely correct that this is the same bug as [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160396/map-of-lists-of-move-only-type-wont-compile). Damn shame the compiler had to make things so difficult to track down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code somewhere is copying subrecord it may be getting hidden in your error messages.

As subrecord is movable but not copyable, you can put this in its header:

```
 struct subrecord 
 { 
       // ...

       subrecord( const subrecord & ) = delete;
       subrecord( subrecord&& ) = default;
 };
```

You might even temporarily comment out the list member and see if any compiler errors come up where this copy is being invoked.

NOTE:

If your compiler doesn't support delete and default, make the copy constructor private but also you have to make the move constructor public.

If this is just a temporary measure to find a compiler error, you can skip implementing it as you don't care about link errors. You'll remove it later, but will have to also remove the private copy-constructor.

Although it is preferential that you do implement it because that will expose any further attempts in  the code to copy a subrecord without giving whoever dares to do it compiler error message hell.

Comment: OK. Deleted previous comment, as the error I got was (as you suspected) due to not making the move constructor visible. Oddly, when I do this, everything compiles. Like there is in fact no copy. The most logical explanation here is probably that @borgleader is right, and I've stumbled over the compiler bug mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160396/map-of-lists-of-move-only-type-wont-compile)

Comment: Ok that doesn't surprise me with VC12 that it isn't fully compliant

Comment: Honestly, I'm just happy to not be using VS6 anymore. :-)